# What symbology to use to show population development?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

In ArcMap I have made a layer containing two cities and the number of population from 1968-2014. I need help with what symbology to use to show the population development for each city. I have tried various quantities and charts but none shows the development i.e. a graph or something.

Any tips in how to show the development trend clearly?

[image: Attribute table]

Comment: What are you trying to show? Change over time? That could be a time-series showing growth each decade, or one map showing % growth since 1968, or any number of other possibilities. What is your end result? A static map? Something interactive? We need some more detail.

Comment: Yes, change over time like growth/decline since 1968 until 2014. The end result is just a basic map with the two cities highlighted and then the graphics to show change over time.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like percent population change between those two years, categorized by symbol size and color for growth/decline.

Comment: That would be good. Any tips regarding were i can read about implementing this?

Comment: Here you go. http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/About_symbolizing_layers_to_represent_quantity/00s500000034000000/

Comment: Okay, I have been looking into this now. It looks like there is no way to use ArcMap for the calculation? That means i need to calculate the percentage difference myself and put the value into the attribute table manualy and that wasn't really how i wanted to do this..

Comment: You can do that with field calculation. Create a new field, right click and field calculate. Something like this (( population_2014 - population_1968 ) / population_1968) * 100.00

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a bar chart to symbolize your population growth but it might get a bit messy since you are dealing with a large time series. Maybe aggregate population by decade and use the bar chart.

Chart symbolizer manual:
http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Using_bar_and_column_charts/00s500000003000000/

Comment: Hmm, then i will have to calculate and aggregate manually and i wanted to make a solution were i use ArcMap for everything without needing to add anything more, if you understand what i mean?